# selectively resolve dependencies of same interface in unity

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, unity-container

We are using Unity framework for Dependency injection. I am registerring two concrete implementations for same class. like...

```
container.RegisterType<IInterface, MyFirstClass>("first");
container.RegisterType<IInterface, MySecondClass>("second");
```

Now there are few classes which has contructer injection for above interface..

```
 public class Class1
    {
       private IInterface _myClass
       public Class1 (IInterface myClass)
       {
         _myClass = myClass // // should be instance of MyFirstClass
       }
 //.. other code
    }

   public class Class2
    {
       private IInterface _myClass

       public Class2 (IInterface myClass)
       {
         _myClass = myClass // should be instance of MySecondClass
       }
 //.. other code
    }
```

So now we want to resolve `IInterface` selectivly in above two classes. `Class1` and `Class2`.

`Class1` should be injeceted with `MyFirstClass` and `Class2` should be injected with `MyFirstClass`. Is this possible to achieve via Unity framework? If not which other IoC frameworks support this?

Please suggest your opinions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```cs
var container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<IInterface, MyFirstClass>("first");
container.RegisterType<IInterface, MySecondClass>("second");
container.RegisterType<Class1>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(typeof(IInterface), "first")));
container.RegisterType<Class2>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter(typeof(IInterface), "second")));
var class1 = container.Resolve<Class1>();
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(class1.MyClass, typeof(MyFirstClass));
var class2 = container.Resolve<Class2>();
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(class2.MyClass, typeof(MySecondClass));

public class MyFirstClass : IInterface
{
}

public class MySecondClass : IInterface
{
}

public interface IInterface
{
}

public class Class1
{
  public IInterface MyClass { get; set; }
  public Class1(IInterface myClass)
  {
    MyClass = myClass;
  }
}
public class Class2
{
  public IInterface MyClass { get; set; }
  public Class2(IInterface myClass)
  {
    MyClass = myClass;
  }
}
```